# Asking unittest to raise an exception on first failure

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

I am trying to debug a failing test. Is there a way to ask `unittest` to not catch an exception from a test, but rather let it go through to the debugger?

It seems `unittest` just added `--failfast` option, but it still catches the exception inside `unittest`, and only stops it from running any further tests.

Comment: Can't you just add the expect block yourself and add some logging there?

Comment: I guess I can. I just need to debug a variety of tests quite often, and thought I could do it without changing anything in the source code.

Comment: You could also write your own subclass of unittest.TestCase where you'd add a common debugging on exceptions. After peaking at the [source code](http://packages.python.org/gchecky/unittest-pysrc.html), I don't think this should be too difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up the source and there is only one exception that comes through.

module: unittest.case

```
            ...
            try:
                testMethod()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                raise
            except ...
```

You can raise this or you will need to overwrite the `run()` method of your testcase and/or use an other result class.